# WYSIWYG disappear after opening bootstrap modal in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel livewire. In Admin Panel summernote WYSIWYG disappear after opening the bootstrap modal I tried other WYSIWYG and all responded the same and didn't show any error in console. But it works perfectly outside the modal.

#### Blade

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="desc1">Desription</label>
  <textarea id="desc1" class="form-control" wire:model.lazy="description" cols="30" rows="10" wire:ignore.self></textarea>
  @error('description') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

#### Script

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#desc1').summernote();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I was able to use `trix-editor` after a tons of research. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539739/is-there-a-proper-way-to-wire-up-trix-editor-with-livewire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this with a parent `div` and use `wire:ignore` on that, like below. remove `wire:ignore.self` from `textarea`. hope this will work..

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div wire:ignore>
    <label for="desc1">Desription</label>
    <textarea id="desc1" class="form-control" wire:model.lazy="description" cols="30" rows="10" ></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```